# When pouring cement next to a home, how far below the mud line on a stucco home do you need to be to avoid water issues?

Tags: concrete, patio

how far below the Mud line on a stucco home do you need to be to avoid water issues 1", 2", 3" or more

Comment: What is this concrete used for? Is it intended to be used a sidewalk or patio?

Answer (score 3):

None.  The concrete should slope away from home.  If you have the option to go an inch down then fine so you don't mess up the stucco while pouring.

Comment: Concrete, or any large flat surface, should be sloped away from the structure at a rate of 1/8" to 1/4" down vertically for every linear foot horizontally to provide sufficient drainage. According to the ADA guidelines, the maximum slope shall be no more than 1" vertically per linear foot horizontally.